# Jquery .load() as include

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im working on a company website that has it's own cms. We don't have access to the server config/ftp and I can not run server-side files, only html/css/js.

I was trying to include the menu using jquery.load() function to make my life easier when my client asks to change some menu item. (The site has more than 20 pages).

The problem is: when I use jquery.load() function, the menu doesn't work properly (it's a menu with slide effect on mouseover) because part of the code is only in the DOM (I guess that's the problem). 
Is there any other way to include the html and keep the menu working?

Comment: Have you tried [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) ?

Comment: Like load the content and then appending it do the div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just used the callback of the load function to call the events of the menu.
Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the events aren't bound since you're loading dynamic content. You'll need to use [delegated events](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) so that they still work for dynamically loaded content.

Comment: Didn't know about it, I will take a look.